# Will mongodb take time to update the index when I update an unrelated field?

Tags: mongodb

I'm concerning with the performance,

say when I do `db.xx.update({a:1}, {c:2})`, will mongodb take extra time to update the index on `{a:1, b:1}`?

is there a way to profile the update operation?

Answer (score 2):

If you change the value of a or b during the update then the index will be updated.  If you don't change either of the values, the index will only be updated if the document had to be relocated on disk during the update process.

The way to tell for sure is to profile your updates - they are logged in `mongod` log if they take longer than 100ms but you can start `mongod` with a lower threshold (using `--slowms` switch) or you can turn on profiling for the DB in question with level 2 and then all operations will be logged into the `system.profile` collection.

Read more about it here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/profile/

Comment: as long as the new (updated) field value is the same SIZE as the value it's replacing, then the index will not be updated.